# jquery function to change text color depending on a special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the text color if there's a negative number in my HTML list

This is my call to my jquery function inside my HTML.

```
<ul id="negativeValidation">
    <li>123.5</li>
    <li>-43.5</li>
</ul>
```

This is my jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#negativeValidation', function() {

        if($("li:contains('-')")== true)
        {
            $("li").css("color", "red");
            console.log("True");
        }else{
            $("li").css("color", "green");
            console.log("False");
        }

    });

});
```

It's not working, when I go to the console I alway get the "false" message so I would like to know what's wrong or if I'm missing something.

Comment: You're going about it differently than I would.  I would just convert to integer, and check if `li.html() < 0`  ...

Comment: also note that the syntax `$('#negativeValidation', function() {` isn't valid or practical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have `console.log('False')` in both cases.

write it like this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9rvky9uv/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#negativeValidation li').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();

    if (txt.indexOf('-') > -1) {
      $(this).css("color", "red");
      console.log("True");
    } else {
      $(this).css("color", "green");
      console.log("False");
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="negativeValidation">
  <li>123.5</li>
  <li>-43.5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$("li:contains('-')")` returns a jQuery object which is always truthy, even if that selector doesn't exist. To test if an element matches you need to use `length` or `is()` but you also are wanting to check each instance

try something like:

```
$('#negativeValidation li').each(function(){
    var color = $(this).is(':contains(-)') ? 'red' :'green';
    $(this).css('color',color);
});
```

A more effective way would be use CSS and add a class for negatives

```
#negativeValidation li {color: green}
#negativeValidation li.negative {color: red}
```

JS

```
$('#negativeValidation li').filter(function(){
    return +$(this).text() < 0; 
}).addClass('negative');
```

Comment: This is nice `return +$(this).text() < 0; `, +1

Comment: @charlieftl Thanks for your time!

Comment: can you tell me the mean to add “+” ? thanks; @charlieftl

Comment: @Anan that casts the value to a number `+"10" === 10`. Try this `console.log(typeof +"10")` will be "number" not "string"

Comment: @Anan  See "Unary plus" operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

Comment: @charlietfl So that more effective way yo say will work better if I want to use that function in a <p> tag?  because I use your example and works perfect for <li> but when I use it inside a <p> tag it puts all the text in red, It doesn't matter if it's negative or positive.

Answer (score 1):

you should need "for":

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#negativeValidation', function() {

   var lis = $('#negativeValidation li');

        for (i = 0; i <= lis.length; i++) {

            if (lis.eq(i).is(':contains(-)')) {
                lis.eq(i).css("color", "red");
                console.log("True");
            } else {
                lis.eq(i).css("color", "green");
                console.log("False");
            }

        }


});
```

});

Comment: you can also use 'each' to replace 'for'

Comment: $("lis') is not the same as `lis` and is invalid selector

Comment: @Anan Thanks for you time :)

Comment: ye,This is my negligence @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the text color if there's a negative number in my
>   HTML list

but problem title refer special characters. Hope you mean to refer only negative numbers.

So in a pure javascript way

```
 // Select all li elements.It will return a collection of matched elements
var getLiItems = document.querySelectorAll("#negativeValidation li");
  // Loop through it , get each's text content ,
      // convert it to float and check if less than 0
 for(var i=0;i<getLiItems.length;i++){
 var getTextContent = parseFloat(getLiItems[i].textContent);
//if less than zero add a class to it
 getTextContent < 0 ? (getLiItems[i].classList.add("negativeColor")): 0;
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jza7L8hh/1/)